# ordering QuerySet in lowercase reverse order

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

The following function is defined in *views.py* for my django project. The only problem I'm having is ordering all of the books by lowercase order (ie Lower()) AND by reverse order (ie '-title' instead of 'title'). I am able to order by one or the other, but not both.

I get the following error:

`Cannot resolve keyword '-title' into field. Choices are: author, date_modified, title`

```
def book_list_title(request):

    all_entries = Book.objects.all().order_by(Lower('-title'))
    books_list=[]

    //Do stuff to create a proper list of books

    return render(request,'books_app/books_list.html', {'books_list':books_list})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Query Expressions`.

```
from django.db.models import Func, F

Book.objects.all().annotate(title_lower=Func(F('title'), function='LOWER')).order_by('-title_lower')
```

Answer (score 5):

Going by the [documentation of `order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) you should be able to just use `desc()` on `Lower()`:

```
all_entries = Book.objects.all().order_by(Lower('title').desc())
```

Comment: This is the best answer